# Using Activator.CreateInstance(Type t), how to cast 'object' to 'T' to add to List<T>

Tags: c#, observablecollection, activator

Working in a custom WPF control, we need to allow the user to add a new object to a list (similar to the ComboBox when IsEditable = true).
The ItemsSource is an ObservableCollection<T>.

When the user enters a string, the control needs to create a new T object and add it to the list.
We have a method to determine what type T is from the ItemsSource object, and then use Activator.CreateInstance() to create a T:

```
 private Type _typ;
 public void AddSomething(object o)
 {
     var iCollection = o as ICollection;
     if (iCollection != null)
     {
        dynamic oc = iCollection;
        _typ = GetGenericType(oc);
        Debug.WriteLine($"    ICollection<T> T type: {_typ}");

        var thng = Activator.CreateInstance(_typ);  

        Debug.WriteLine($"    thng Type: {thng.GetType()}");  
        
        ItemsSourceClass.Things.Add(thng as _typ);  
        // Compile time error:
        CS0246  The type or namespace name '_typ' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
        /* snip */
```

This all works as expected - thng is a new instance of T - until we try to add the new object to the ItemsSource collection.

Since Activator.CreateInstance(Type t) returns *object*, it seems like we need to cast thng to *T* to add to the ObservableCollection<T>.
We have tried various ways to convince the ItemsSource collection that thng is the correct type, but have not found one that works.
What are we missing?
**Update**
We added a dependency variable:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ListObjectTypeProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("ListObjectType", typeof(Type), typeof(AutoCompleteComboBox));
```

In xaml:

```
   ListObjectType="{x:Type local:SimpleClass}"
```

This usage of the ListObjectTypeProperty delivers the correct object, but it still is Type *object*:

Same result doing it this way:

```
   var assemName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

   var thng = Activator.CreateInstance(assemName, ListObjectType.FullName);
   var thng2 = thng.Unwrap();
```

Comment: Why isn't the containing class generic also, then you can just say `var thng = new T();`? You cannot do `as MyTypeVariable`, it's not valid

Comment: What is the type of `ItemsSourceClass.Things`?

Comment: @Charlieface This code is in a control that could be handed an ICollection<T> where T could be almost anything.

Comment: @canton7 public class SimpleClass { public string Name {get; set;} public string Color {get; set;} public int Count {get; set;}

Comment: @Cat There's no `Add` method on your `SimpleClass`... What is the type of `ItemsSourceClass.Things`?

Comment: The you need `if(_typ.IsInstanceOfType(thng)) ItemsSourceClass.Things.Add(thng);`

Comment: @canton7 ItemsSourceClass.Things is ObservableCollection<SimpleClass>.

Comment: Is it always an `ObservableCollection<SimpleClass>`, or might it actually be an `ObservableCollection<SomethingElse>`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use reflection to call `Add` also:

```
ItemsSourceClass.Things
    .GetType()
    .GetMethod(nameof(ItemsSourceClass.Things.Add))
    .Invoke(ItemsSourceClass.Things, new object[] { thng });
```